# How do you return an object from python to QML?

Tags: python, return, signals-slots, pyside, qml

I'm trying to return a QObject from a Slot.  I'm using PySide and QML.  My code looks like this:

```
class myClass(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.object = QtCore.QObject()

    QtCore.Slot(result=object)
    def myFunc(self):
        return self.object
```

When I console.log the return value I get:

```
QVariant(PySide::PyObjectWrapper)
```

I can't seem to get the value out of this thing.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?  I can return primitive types (like int, str, etc.), but objects, lists, and dicts are beyond me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am trying to access properties of an object using dot notation.  If somebody could show me an example of this, it would be very helpful.  However, if I could just get the object back I think I could go the distance by myself.  Thanks again!

Thanks

Jack

Comment: What does the QML look like? What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Wow! I didn't realise how old this question was!

Answer (score 2):

So, here is something that does what I *think* you're trying to do. When you click anywhere, the blue area changes green. This is done by changing the color property on the object that is passed by a signal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtDeclarative import QDeclarativeView
from PySide.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget

def some_function(passed_object):
    passed_object.setProperty("color", "green")

def main(argv):
    app = QApplication(argv)

    display_widget = QDeclarativeView()
    display_widget.setViewport(QGLWidget())

    display_widget.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    display_widget.setSource(QtCore.QUrl('pass_an_object.qml'))

    display_widget.rootObject().object_signal.connect(some_function)

    display_widget.show()
    display_widget.resize(640,480)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

With the accompanying qml file (I've called it pass_an_object.qml):

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: foo
    width: 640
    height: 640
    color: "red"

    signal object_signal(variant foo)

    Rectangle {
        id: an_object
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "blue"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            object_signal(an_object)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this sends object from qml to python. How to send object from python to qml?